# SVG Filter tag need manual render on DOM

Tags: javascript

Need one Help, I have added a **filter** tag inside **SVG** tag and the filter attribute didn't worked until I manually change anything on DOM and re-render.

[HTML Online Code](https://codebeautify.org/alleditor/y23372b9f)

Please try the above html and when click on button you can see changes in DOM. but you manually need to update it to see the changes on screen.